# Numbering of figures within theorems

Tags: floats, numbering, captions, theorems

I have a lot of Theorems and within them some Figures, which I have to number according to the respective Theorem number. In principle, this works fine with `\numberwithin{figure}{Theorem}`. However, if I only have one Figure within a Theorem (e.g. within Theorem 1) I only want it to be called "Figure 1" instead of "Figure 1.1" Is there a way to do so?

Here is an example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\numberwithin{figure}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}
This is Theorem 1.

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering Figure
  \caption{This should be Figure 1 (instead of Figure 1.1).}
\end{figure}
\end{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem}
This is Theorem 2.

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering Figure
  \caption{This is Figure 2.1.}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering Figure
  \caption{This is Figure 2.2.}
\end{figure}
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the figure-related graphs mustn't "float" (in the LaTeX-specific sense of the word), you probably shouldn't be using `figure` environments to begin with for those graphs. Instead, use `minipage` environments and `\captionof{figure}{...}` statements to create figure-like captions. Finally, for those theorems with more than one graph, issue the instruction

```
\counterwithin{figure}{Theorem}
```

immediately before the start of the theorem-like environment and

```
\counterwithout{figure}{Theorem}
```

immediately after the end of the environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}
This is Theorem 1.

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\upshape
  \centering 
  Figure
  \captionof{figure}{This is Figure 1.}
\end{minipage}
\end{Theorem}

\counterwithin{figure}{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem}
This is Theorem 2.

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\upshape
  \centering 
  Figure
  \captionof{figure}{This is Figure 2.1.}

  \bigskip
   Figure
  \captionof{figure}{This is Figure 2.2.}
\end{minipage}
\end{Theorem}

\counterwithout{figure}{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem}
This is Theorem 3.

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\upshape
  \centering 
  Figure
  \captionof{figure}{This is Figure 3.}
\end{minipage}
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine, thanks. However, since I have not yet used `minipage` at all, what exactly is the advantage of using it instead of `figure` environments?

Comment: @Jack - The disadvantage of the `figure` environment -- at least when used in theorem-like environments -- is that there's no guarantee that the `figure` environment will actually be placed right where you want it to be. That cannot happen with `minipage` environments.

Comment: I have just identified a challenge with the proposed solution: If I have a Theorem without any figure, then the numbering of the subsequent figures goes wrong. For example, if you would change your Theorem 3 to Theorem 4 and add a new Theorem 3 without any Figure before, then the figure in Theorem 4 is still called "Figure 3". Is there a solution for this as well?

Comment: @Jack - If theorems 2 and 4 are associated with figures but theorem 3 is not, you could issue the instruction `\stepcounter{figure}` immediately before theorem 4. If you've guess that `\stepcounter` increments its argument (which must be a counter variable) by 1, you'd be entirely correctly. If there are several theorems without associated figures, the `\setcounter` instruction may be more useful. (Before the start of theorem `7`, say, issue the instruction `\setcounter{figure}{6}`.)